# adding score to div

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to render score on screen. When i appendChild, it creates an array. Is there a way to update instead of appending?

```
function screenScore() {
    let screen = new Text("score: " + score);
    document.getElementById('score').appendChild(screen);
    // document.getElementById('score').last().update(screen);
}
```

```
function setupKeyboardControls() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        // console.log(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            moveLeft();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            moveUp();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            moveRight();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            moveDown();
        }
        eraseMap();
        drawMap();
        console.log(score);
        screenScore();
        // removeScore();
    });
}
```

```
<body>
    <div id="score"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you call your setupKeyboardControls function?

Comment: function main() {
    drawMap();
    setupKeyboardControls();
    // screenScore();
}

main();

Comment: Just set the textContent of the elelemnt. NOt sure why you are appending. `document.getElementById('score').textContent = "score: " + score;`

Comment: `"message": "ReferenceError: drawMap is not defined",`. Also: `eraseMap` is not defined.

Comment: @connexo why did you make it runnable when it is just a portion of the code? lol, It does nothing to help the question.

Comment: @epascarello To show OP the they need to present runnable code that reproduces the problem. MCVE anyone?

Comment: The problem is clear and does not need the full code.

Comment: *When i appendChild, it creates an array* no, its absolutely not clear. You're just assuming it's clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use `innerText` instead of `appendChild`

```
document.getElementById('score').innerText = "score: " + score;
```

Update: As stated by others in the comments, it's better to use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` for security reasons so I updated my example.

Comment: Surely you would **never** use such a problematic property as `innerHTML` for updating text. The correct property for this purpose is `textContent`.

Comment: May I ask why is it problematic? PS I work with Angular most of the time so don't use native API that often.

Comment: Cross Site scripting is not going to be a issue here when the OP is using their own code! lol.

Comment: @epascarello Wrong again. `let screen = new Text("score: " + score);` with  `score` seemingly being a global variable - the doors are **W I D E** open here.

Comment: @CharlesBamford I wasn't the one writing *lol* (twice). I just stated factual information.

Comment: There is an assumption there would be a XSS here without actually seeing the code. You already complained in comments there was not enough code. It is 99.314% chance there is no XSS hole. Again, you can not prove there is or there is not with the code provided by the OP. Yes textContent or innerText is the preferred method when you are just setting text, but innerHTML is not going to cause issues if the data is not from user input or an outside source.

Comment: @epascarello, It may be inconsequential in this case, but it's important to teach best practices. It's as valid to assume that the score variable is dangerous as it is to assume that it is not.

Comment: Please note that `innerText` is non-standard. Really, `textContent` is the property of choice here.